# How to run processes with Invoke-WMIMethod on remote computer in foreground

Tags: windows, wmi, powershell-2.0

I am running this command

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName $machine -Credential $cred -Impersonation 3 -Path Win32_process -Name create -ArgumentList "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\Windows_Updates.ps1" -Verbose
```

The only problem is in the remote machine, it getting created as a background process. When I open the task manager, I am able to see powershell.exe, but I have no way to identify what is going on. I have looked nearly everywhere but unable to find a solution.

Basically I need to execute the powershell file remotely. I am open to using other solutions where I can see the script running.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that is possible.  Try psexec instead

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/09/06/how-can-i-remotely-start-an-interactive-process.aspx

sysinternals psexec
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Comment: yes, I am aware of psexec. Was looking for a native powershell solution.

Comment: well a WMI solution I guess.  This other article says that after 2000sp3 microsoft disable remote interactive process.  This article has an example that uses task scheduler like the technet blog http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/vbscript/rem-using-wmi-to-create-remote-interactive-processes